# Improve code of logarithmic quantizer

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-equations

I am implementing a logarithmic quantizer which is defined as follows:

$$ q(u) = \begin{cases} u_i , \frac{u_i}{1+\delta} < u < \frac{u_i}{1-\delta} \\
0 , 0 \leq u \leq \frac{u_o}{1+\delta} \\
-q(-u), \ u < 0 \end{cases} $$

where the different parameters are computed based upon these expressions:

$$ u_i = p^{1-i}u_o, \ i = 1,2,\dots $$
$$ \delta = \frac{1-p}{1+p} $$
$$ u_{min} = \frac{u_o}{1+\delta} $$

More information regarding the quantizer can be found at this paper: [Adaptive Backstepping Control of Uncertain Nonlinear Systems with Input Quantization](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6760767).

In order to code a function to implement it in MATLAB, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
function q_u = logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(u,step,u_min)

    u_o = u_min*(1+step);
    p = (1-step)/(1+step);
    
    if u < 0
        
        q_u = -logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(-u,step,u_min);
        
    elseif ( (u >= 0) && (u <= u_o/(1+step)) )
        
        q_u = 0;
        
    else
        
        i = 1;
        
        while (1)
            
            u_i = p^(1-i) * u_o;
            
            if ( (u > u_i/(1+step)) && (u <= u_i/(1-step)) )
                
                q_u = u_i;
                break;
                
            end
            
            i = i + 1;   
        end
    end 
end
```

Now, my issue is to improve the code as much as I can. For example, the `while(1)` loop, which codes the different quantization levels, is something that should go away and be replaced. Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is not really what this particular StackExchange forum is there for: Optimize code. But separately, before you optimize, what is your evidence that the code as is is actually problematic and *needs* to be optimized?

Comment: Yes, I know about the particular forum but I had to include equations and stackoverflow doesn't allow MathJax at all, as far as I know. Code works but this kind of infinite loop being broken at some time, isn't a good programming technique. That is why I would like some advice.

Comment: You can include formulas by delimiting them with dollar signs, as usual in LaTeX. If your goal is just advise on how to program, or improve code, there is a whole StackExchange forum for just that.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Math works on all the SE sites I use... except StackOverflow itself. Atwood makes a strong statement [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60023/285968), but see also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106281/mathjax-should-also-work-in-stackoverflow) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation).